# Ctags failes to sort big tags

Tags: out-of-memory, ctags

I'm working with big project. ctags run with only c++ specific options generates 4GB file when it reports "ctags.exe: out of memory: cannot sort tag file"
Exuberant Ctags 5.8

How to work with those kind of projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried github [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags-win32/releases) and [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ctags) ctags package. Both of them worked and solved my problem.